# Disconnected inverse limit

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am looking for a inverse sequence $Y = \lim \limits_{\longleftarrow} \{ X_n ,f_n\}$ of connected topological spaces $X_n$ that is disconnected. When $X_n$ are continua then $Y$ is continuum, hence spaces $X_n$ need to be noncompact. I was trying to find appropriate bonding function $g=f_n$ when $X_n = \mathbb R$ but with no success. Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know an example in $\def\R{\mathbf R}\R$, but $\R^2$ will do, I think. Let 
$$ X_n = [0,1] \times \{0,1\} \cup \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} \left(\left\{\frac 1k\right\} \times [0,1] \right)$$
and $f_n: X_{n+1}\to X_n$ the inclusion. Then each $X_n$ is connected, but the inverse limit
 $$ \varprojlim X_n = \bigcap_n X_n = [0,1]\times \{0,1\} $$
is not.

Comment: Thank You. That extra dimension really helps :-D